# Regular expressions in chef

Tags: regex, chef-infra, dsl, chef-recipe

How do we use regular expressions/pattern matching in a chef recipe.
In my default.rb recipe, for example:

```
case node["env_name"]
when "admin-dev"
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-dev"
when "admin-dit"
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-dev"
when "admin-perf1"
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-qa"
when "admin-perf2"
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-qa"
else
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-prod" 
end
```

Is there any way I can do something like "admin-d*"  or "admin-d[a-z]*" to match the strings admin-dev and admin-dit. I tried a bunch of stuff including the above ones but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly I like to use a hash to do this kind of mapping like this (and in attributes):

attribute.rb

```
env_to_suffix = 
{ 
  "admin-dev" => "dev",
  "admin-dit" => "dev",
  "admin-perf1" => "qa",
  "admin-perf2" => "qa"
}
default['company']['env_suffix'] = env_to_suffix[node.chef_environment] || "prod"
```

in recipe.rb

```
include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-#{node['company]['env_suffix']}"
```

I find it easier to maintain in long term and it allow a per node override for edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

It's a ruby code, so regular expression matching works the [same way as in ruby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm).

```
case node["env_name"]
when /admin-d(ev)|(it)/
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-dev"
when /admin-perf[12]/
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-qa"
else
     include_recipe "lxsetup-deploy::lxsetup-prod" 
end
```